# Generating text file dynamically and display it in new browser window

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created text file and added content to it.

After this I want above generated text file should display in web browser and can save file as .txt format.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\overflow.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
writer.Write("Hello Welcome");
writer.Close();
```

Comment: This isn't really clear, is this a desktop application you want displayed in the default browser, or is this a web application you want to redirect the current page to the text file after its created?

Comment: it's web application , i just want create text file dynamically and set it's content. Later that text file along with it's content should display in new browser window .

Comment: @jai_kenche You want to export your content as `txt` file?

Comment: exactly but i want that text file displayed its contents in the browser

Comment: @jai_kenche, Do you want to displayed when they click a button on the page?

Comment: There are *many* problems associated with this.... I'll let you discover them.

Answer (score 2):

The sample code below is for ASPX.Net app:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // get a temporary file name so we don't conflict with concurrent user
        string fileName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
        fileName = Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, "txt");

        // Now map the file to a path within the host directory
        string outputFileName = MapPath(fileName);

        // write some data to the file
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs);

        writer.WriteLine("Hello Welcome");
        writer.WriteLine("Input Box: " + this.TextBox1.Text);
        writer.WriteLine(string.Empty);
        writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        writer.Close();

        // now open the url in another browser tab
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "windowKey", "window.open('" + fileName + "');", true);
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Create Temp File</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <p>Generate a temporary text file and display in browser</p>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Web Page with Button:**

[image: sample code running]

**Web Page displaying text file:**

[image: Sample code displaying text file]